# What if the ResourceManager down?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, resourcemanager

In the newest version of Hadoop mapreduce(called 'Yarn'), JobTracker(exists in previous version) has been replaced by the ResourceManager(called 'RM') and ApplicationMaster. 
In official document about Yarn architecture, there are no words say that how many RMs are there in a MapReduce cluster, and the given graph about Yarn architecture shows only 1 RM exists in a cluster.

So, what if the only RM down? If there are several RMs, how do they work together?

Hope someone can explain it to me. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is 1 RessourceManager per rack but you can have several racks in your cluster.

If you try to submit a job while RessourceManager is down, Hadoop will try to connect to the RessourceManager because it needs it to execute the job.

Here is an example of the logs when the RM is down and try to submit a job :

```
14/06/06 09:39:54 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: hadoop01.sii.fr/10.6.6.211:8032. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
14/06/06 09:39:55 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: hadoop01.sii.fr/10.6.6.211:8032. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
14/06/06 09:39:56 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: hadoop01.sii.fr/10.6.6.211:8032. Already tried 3 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
```

When the RM is back, the job is submitting correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry to view the answer so late. But could you please explain that how these RMs work together? I mean that if there are several RMs in different racks, and a job should be submitted to Hadoop, which RM would be used and how? Thanks.

Comment: According to your answer, If the only RM down in a cluster, where are the jobs saved to? How many times would Hadoop try to connect the RM? Is it configurable? I'm newer to Hadoop, hope you can explain to me if you know. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I can't answer to your first question because i have a small architecture without only one RM :D
About the second question wshat do you mean by "jobs saved" ? The RM will try to reconnect till the job is running i.e you don't kill it.